# Changing Backspace effect in Tkinter text widget

Tags: python, replace, tkinter, backspace, strikethrough

I am looking for a way to change the Backspace key effect in a Tkinter text widget. I am monitoring the key events in the Text Window from Tkinter, and I would need to find a way to :

- Disable the effect of the Backspace key, but still be able know it was typed
- Strikethrough the character the user was intending to delete

I have no idea where to start with that. I can single out the Backspace event, but do not know how to prevent it from deleting a character. I also don't know how affect the input in real time (apply a strikethrough 'style' to the character(s) as the user is writing)

Here is what I have for now, but that's not much :

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
root=Tk()
root.title("TextnonEdit")
text=Text(root)
text.grid()

def keepit(key):
    print key.keysym
    if key.keysym == "BackSpace":
        print "do not delete, strikethrough"

# Bind entry to keypress
text.bind("<Key>", keepit)

def saveas():
    global text
    t = text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    savelocation=tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
    file1=open(savelocation, "w+")
    file1.write(t)
    file1.close()

button=Button(root, text="Save", command=saveas)
button.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for any answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be solved by doing the following:

1. create a tag on the text widget with the `overstrike` attribute set to true
2. create a binding on the backspace character to apply the tag
3. have the bound function return `"break"` to prevent the default behavior

### Example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # add a tag that lets us apply the overstrike attribute
        self.text.tag_configure("overstrike", overstrike=True)

        # add a binding on the backspace key
        self.text.bind("<BackSpace>", self.handleBackspace)

    def handleBackspace(self, event):
        # add the overstrike to the character before the
        # insertion cursor
        self.text.tag_add("overstrike", "insert-1c", "insert")

        # move the cursor to the previous position
        self.text.mark_set("insert", "insert-1c")

        # prevent the default behaviour
        return "break"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Brian ! Here is what I got after a few adjustments to get it to work with multiple backspaces in a row and deleted selections :

```
import Tkinter as tk

x = 0

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        # add a tag that lets us apply the overstrike attribute
        self.text.tag_configure("overstrike", overstrike=True)


        self.text.bind("<Key>", self.eyeout)

        # add a binding on the backspace key
        self.text.bind("<BackSpace>", self.handleBackspace)

    def eyeout(self, key):
        global x
        print key.keysym
        # move the cursor to the previous position
        self.text.mark_set("insert", "insert+" + str(x) + "c")

        print "insert+" + str(x) + "c"

        #reset consecutive backspace count to zero

        x = 0

    def handleBackspace(self, event):

        if self.text.tag_ranges(tk.SEL):
            print ('Selected text !')
            #if text is selected, overstrike all the selection
            self.text.tag_add("overstrike", "sel.first", "sel.last")
            # move cursor to end of selection
            self.text.mark_set("insert", "sel.last")
            # deselect to avoid overwrite
            self.text.tag_remove(tk.SEL, "sel.first", "sel.last")
            # counting doesn't apply to selection, reset backspace count
            global x
            x = 0
        else:
            print('NO Selected Text')
            # add the overstrike to the character before the
            # insertion cursor
            self.text.tag_add("overstrike", "insert-1c", "insert")
            # counting system to know how many backspaces in a row were entered
            print "Backspace!"
            print x
            global x
            x = x+1
            print x
            print "Backspace increase"
            self.text.mark_set("insert", "insert-1c")

        # prevent the default behaviour
        return "break"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```